# Pixel analysis using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am very new to QGIS and I have two tif images which I need to do pixel analysis on, so that I can compare the change in vegetation over time.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the raster classification plugin for QGIS.  Here is a link that explains the plugin:
http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/Raster_classification_with_DTclassifier_for_QGIS